# Displaying authentication errors in Vue login component not working using push

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm a beginner in Laravel and Vue, I'm taking a course at Udemy, trying to display a failed authentication error response within a Vue component using push if the error is a 422 error, (this is only for testing purposes to know if push works or the code will run if used later. The code will be refactored).

I've done some research and found no answers at the moment.

```
<template>


 <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="card card-shadowed p-50 w-400 mb-0" style="max-width: 100%">
          <h5 class="text-uppercase text-center">Login</h5>
          <br><br>
    <form>
      <ul class="list-group alert alert-danger" v-if="errors.length > 0">
        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="error in errors" :key="errors.indexOf(error)">
           {{ error }}
        </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" v-model="email">
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" v-model="password">
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group flexbox py-10">
              <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  v-model="remember" checked>
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="custom-control-description">Remember me</span>
              </label>
    
              <a class="text-muted hover-primary fs-13" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-bold btn-block btn-primary" @click="attemptLogin()" :disabled="!isValidLoginForm()" type="button">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <p class="text-center text-muted fs-13 mt-20">Don't have an account? <a href="page-register.html">Sign up</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        import axios from 'axios';
        import qs from 'qs';
        export default {
            mounted() {
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            },
            data() {
              return {
                email: '',
                password: '',
                remember: true,
                loading: false,
                errors: [],
              }
            },
            methods: {
              emailIsValid() {
               if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(this.email)) {
                  return true
                } else {
                  return false
                }
              },
    
              isValidLoginForm() {
                return this.emailIsValid() && this.password && !this.loading
              },
    
              attemptLogin() {
          

      var the_data = {
                  email: this.email,
                  password: this.password,
                  remember: this.remember,
                }
                this.errors = [];
                this.loading = true;
                axios.post('/login', the_data)
                .then(function (response) {
                  location.reload();
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  this.loading = false;
                  if (error.response.status == 422) {
                    this.errors.push("We couldn't verify your account details.");
                  } else {
                    this.errors.push("Something went wrong, please refresh and try again.");
                  }
                });
              }
            },
    
            // computed: {
            //
            // },
        }
    </script>
```

I get no errors in my view when I put in wrong user credentials, but the console outputs a 422 error response (I need a readable response to be displayed in the alert e.g. "We couldn't verify your account details" but no luck).

Comment: You don't need `qs.stringify(the_data)`, simply pass-in/use `the_data`

Comment: @Noogen you are right, I don't need it, axios post works perfectly without it. However, this part of my code doesn't still work
 
 `.catch(function (error) {`
                  `this.loading = false;`
                 ` if (error.response.status == 422) {`
                    `this.errors.push("We couldn't verify your account details.");`
                 ` } else {`
                   ` this.errors.push("Something went wrong, please refresh and try again.");
                  }`

i still get no response from push `if (error.response.status === 422)`

Comment: Ok, try changing `this.errors = [];` line to `this.errors.length = 0` so you don't overwrite the array variable that is being watched.  Also, I'm assuming you do get 422 result but you're just not seeing the error?

Comment: @Noogen Yes I get the 422 error in the console but I don't get the response in the component. For some reason changing the format of the then and catch, blocks made it work. will post code below

Answer (score 1):

After taking out qs.stringify as suggested by @Noogen above; for some reason changing the structure of the 'then and catch blocks' solved the problem (now outputting a 422 console error and pushing error to the component as expected):
`

```
 attemptLogin() {
    var the_data = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
      remember: this.remember,
    }
    this.errors = [];
    this.loading = true;
    axios.post('/login', the_data)
    .then(response => {
      location.reload();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.loading = false;
        console.log(error.response)
        if (error.response.status == 422) {
           this.errors.push("We couldn't verify your account details.");
         } else {
           this.errors.push("Something went wrong, please refresh and try again.");
         }
    });
  }
},`
```